# React, MongoDB, Mongoose: How to format my date to be readable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, mern

Using MERN-stack to build an app (MongoDB, ExpressJS, ReactJS, NodeJS)

I know there are plenty of docs/other solutions on stackoverflow for similar issues.

However, what confuses me about my scenario is that I'm not creating a `new Date()` object and then rendering it.

I have a backend model set up that has an attribute for Date, using Mongoose:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const UserSchema = new Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
})

module.exports = User = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema)
```

Now I'm simply rendering the user's data on a component/page but it comes out as

```
2020-05-10T17:57:14.987Z
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `moment` library like so:

[Documentation here](https://momentjs.com/docs/)

```
const myTime = moment(dateFromDB).format('hh:mm:ss') // or any other format
```